# ng-disabled with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, aem

I am writing a condition in an AEM/CQ in jsp where:

```
ng-disabled="${!properties.enableSignInButton} || ${!(!loginForm.logInCOFInput.$invalid)} || ${(captchaShow && !captchaValidated)}"
```

which doesn't seems to be working.

When I print this in jsp, I get:
|||| in the page where '||' is printed literally without resolving it. Seems that is what is happening inside the ng-disabled.

Comment: Is captchaShow is in scope ? why $ is used before it. Can you send code snippet

Comment: Print out those variables SEPARETALY just with the scriplet syntax and show us the output. By the way you shouldn't mix this to a JSP. Pass them to angular in form of a JSON, and dont put the templates through JSP translation, just use static HTML instead

Answer (score 1):

two conditon must true means use "&&"

`ng-disabled = "condition1 && condition2"`

Any one condition true means use "||"

`ng-disabled = "condition1 || condition2"`

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled receives an expression there is no need to use

```html
ng-disabled="!properties.enableSignInButton || !(!loginForm.logInCOFInput.$invalid) || (captchaShow && !captchaValidated)"
```

Comment: It was jSP scriptlet syntax I guess